# animating image in heart beat form by xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have inserted an image in the view.No I need to set an animation in a way that it glows on and off (like heartbeat action) when user selects that image.What will be the code for that?please help me.

Comment: and the prize for the best do my homework question goes to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[imageHeartBeated setAlphaValue:0.5];
```

to set the alpha lower, which will make it glow "off".

I hope you're not just lazy, as one commenter pointed out, but just do not know where to start. It would be [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You should also peruse Ray Wenderlich's fabulous [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-animation), I'm pointing you at the two posts that might be of use to you for this particular purpose.